# Error on scala class : recursive method printExpr needs result type

Tags: scala

I'm getting an error on line :

```
case Sum(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("+"); printExpr(r)
```

error is :

> recursive method printExpr needs result type

This code looks ok to me, what am I doing wrong ?

```
abstract class Expr {

  case class Num(n: Int) extends Expr
  case class Sum(l: Expr , r: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Prod(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr

  def evalExpr(e: Expr): Int = e match {
    case Num(n) => n
    case Sum(l, r) => evalExpr(l) + evalExpr(r)
    case Prod(l, r) => evalExpr(l) * evalExpr(r)
  }

  def printExpr(e: Expr) = e match {
    case Num(n) => print(" " + n + " ")
    case Sum(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("+"); printExpr(r)
    case Prod(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("x"); printExpr(r)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recursive methods in Scala need an explicitly stated return type, as the error message states.

The reason is that Scala infers the method's return type from the types used in the method body. When the method's return type *affects* the types used in the method body (because it calls itself recursively), Scala isn't able to figure out what type it should assign to the method, so it requires that you do so in the source code (as you have with `evalExpr`, where you explicitly said that it returns an `Int`).

In this case, you want `printExpr` to have return type `Unit`, which is the type of uninteresting values with no information. Usually calling a method with return type `Unit` is only done for its side effects (such as `print`).

So you can change the header line of `printExpr` to:

```
def printExpr(e: Expr) : Unit = e match {
```

Alternatively, Scala has some syntactic sugar for declaring "procedures". You can think of a "procedure" as not returning anything, and just executing some code, but really every method in Scala returns *something*; "procedures" are just methods that return type `Unit`. The syntax for doing so is to omit the `=` after the method's header, but then you *must* surround the method body with curly braces (even if it's a single expression, like your `match`). So you could do:

```
def printExpr(e: Expr) {
  e match {
    ...
  }
}
```

to avoid explicitly declaring `Unit`.

Answer (score 4):

Scala compile cant infer types for recursive methods, so you must declare it explicitly:

```
def printExpr(e: Expr): Unit = e match {
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a return type to `printExpr(e : Expr)` like `String` or `Expr` for example

```
printExpr(e : Expr): Expr
printExpr(e : Expr): String
```