# Recursive call of function which return function

Tags: scala, function

I need a help with the syntax.

Question: How can I call method recursively in this situation?

Please find the error in the code below:

```
def increase[T: Numeric](x: T) = (y: T) => { 
    require( implicitly[Numeric[T]].gt(x , 0.asInstanceOf[T] ) )
    if ( implicitly[Numeric[T]].gt(y , 0.asInstanceOf[T] ) )  
        implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, y)
    else                
        increase[T](x)(implicitly[Numeric[T]].abs(y))
}

val inc =  increase[Int] _

println(inc(5)(-1))
```

Here is error code:
c:\Sources>cd scala

c:\Sources\scala>scala main.scala
c:\Sources\scala\main.scala:29: error: recursive method increase needs result ty
pe
                        increaseT( implicitly[Numeric[T]].abs(y) )
                        ^
one error found

c:\Sources\scala>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on scala class : recursive method printExpr needs result type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260275/error-on-scala-class-recursive-method-printexpr-needs-result-type)

Comment: Also - please post errors as text, not images.

Comment: I am return function from function so not sure if this is a good idea to change function signature.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. Functions in Scala are objects like any other, and recursive methods need an explicit type annotation.

Comment: So, as I understand I have to define returning type separately? not in the way of anonymous function etc ?

Comment: Yes, you have to provide a type annotation for the `increase` method, so it will look like `def increase[T: Numeric](x: T): TypeOfFunctionReturned = ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your function definition.

1. Due to how context bounds work, `def increase[T: Numeric](x: T) = (y: T) => ???` acts as something like `def increase[T](x: T)(implicit ev: Numeric[T])(y: T)`. The implicit argument list is between the normal ones, so it's not possible to just provide both `x` and `y` one after another. So, `increase(x)(abs(y))` won't work, you'd have to use something like `increase(x).apply(abs(y))`.
2. You shouldn't use `0.asInstanceOf[T]`. For example, if `T` is `BigInt`, this becomes `0.asInstanceOf[BigInt]` and results in a runtime exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to scala.math.BigInt`. You can use `implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero` instead.
3. Having those `implicitly[Numeric[T]]` everywhere is not very pretty. It's better to have a fixed name for this implicit argument, and import the implicit operations, so it will be possible to use `x > num.zero` and `x + y`. See the example below.
4. And as mentioned in the comments, you have to explicitly specify the return type of a recursive function. In your case it should be `T => T`.

So, with all this you can have the following definition for the increase method:

```
def increase[T](x: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T => T = (y: T) => {
  import num._

  require(x > num.zero)
  if (y > num.zero) x + y
  else increase(x).apply(y.abs)
}

val inc =  increase[Int] _

println(inc(5)(-1))
```

Also, you can have a similar definition without using an anonymous function:

```
def increase[T](x: T)(y: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  import num._

  require(x > num.zero)
  if (y > num.zero) x + y
  else increase(x)(y.abs)
}
```

And just in case, here you don't even have to make it recursive:

```
def increase[T](x: T)(y: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = {
  import num._

  require(x > num.zero)
  x + y.abs
}
```

Comment: Alright, I see. This looks like good and detailed answer for me. Looks  like have to improve scala knowledge in few areas. Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm: T => T = (y: T) here you defining return type for function. I am a bit confused with the part after arrow.. what kind of construction is that? thanks

Comment: @PavelOliynyk `T => T` is the return type, then you have `=` and then the function definition starts: `(y: T)`. It's like in your code, with an added `T => T` type definition. And `A => B` is a type of a function, that takes an argument of type `A` and returns a result of type `B`. `A => B` is actually syntactic sugar for `Function1[A, B]`.

Comment: One more thing to ask. I've notice you have imported implicit in the scope of function. So literally  this will be done at run time when actual type specified ??

Comment: @PavelOliynyk I'm not sure what exactly you mean. By itself `import` doesn't do any runtime work, it's just adding some names and implicit conversions to the namespace during compilation. And for example if you reify (with Scala reflection) my last `increase` definition (the one with `x + y.abs`), you'd see that after implicit resolution it becomes `def increase[T](x: T)(y: T)(implicit num: `package`.Numeric[T]): T = {
    import num._;
    Predef.require(num.mkOrderingOps(x).$greater(num.zero));
    num.mkNumericOps(x).$plus(num.mkNumericOps(y).abs())
  };`